# Question about combining data from two tables with many to many relationship

Tags: database, database-design

Could anyone please explain (or link to a good tutorial) on how to combine data from two tables which is connected with a 'link-table'?

- One table contains question
- One table contains categories
- One table contains question_categories

Each question belongs to many categories, and each category can have many questions.

The link table contain two id's, categoryID and questionID(they are primary keys in the table) with a foreign key to category and question table.

But I do not completely understand how I can write an SQL select that for instance displays what kind of categories question with ID 2 belongs to.

And thorough explanation would be MUCH appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [`JOIN`](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-join-sql-tutorial/) clause to connect the tables.

```
SELECT Q.* 
FROM question Q
  INNER JOIN question_categories QC
    ON q.questionId = QC.questionID
WHERE QC.categoryID = 2
```

To break it down:

```
SELECT Q.*  -- Get all fields from the alias Q (though you should specify fields)
FROM question Q -- From the question table, aliased Q
  INNER JOIN question_categories QC -- Join on the question_categories table (QC)
    ON q.questionId = QC.questionID -- Using the questionIds on both tables as join criteria
WHERE QC.categoryID = 2 -- constrain to only categoryId of 2
```

---

Edit (example for categories by questionId) as requested in comments:

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM category C
  INNER JOIN question_categories QC
    ON C.categoryId = QC.categoryID
WHERE QC.questionID = 1
```

Comment: But would I write a select query where I want all categories that let say, questionID = 1 belongs too?

Comment: @Andreas Johannessen - In a similar manner. Just use the `category` table to join on, using the `categoryId` field and constraining to `questionId` of 1.

Comment: @Andreas Johannessen - I suggest you start reading about SQL Joins. They are an essential part of the language.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you commented before I asked, but I forgot to change one part of the join. Do you have any advice or links to where I can read more about this? I only had one course about basic SQL, 1 year ago so it is a bit rusty.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) are good resources and [this](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/) one also appears to be a good basic tutorial.

Comment: @Andreas Johannessen - Welcome :)